# How do I create an element on a page which always stays visible but moves out of the way of other elements?

Tags: html, fixed

I have a HTML page which a pretty complex layout ([see here](http://www.pdark.de/haul/SceneFile-f446bc18-fdbc-42dd-bfde-2f501e2e7f73.html)). I need to put an image on that page which the visitor can drag anywhere so she can remember where she was. I've implemented the bookmark feature but now I need to place the image somewhere where she can easily grab it.

Basically, I'd like the element to stay below the ToC on the right but it shouldn't scroll out of view.

I guess I could use JavaScript to move the element as soon as it starts to scroll out of view but is there a better option? Can I say "float right and below the ToC div or view.top, whichever is greater"?

Or maybe I should create a fixed header (with the links and the maybe the ToC)?

Any other ideas?

Comment: Because there is more than one solution.

Comment: maybe, but then, there always are. This is not really a CW question IMO.

Comment: Let me put this another way: Because I think that there isn't one simple solution so I hope that several people will work on each answer to improve them. The solution is probably too complex for just 10 points.

Comment: what you say applies to many questions on SO. If it's too complex for 10 points, it should be a *bounty*, not CW :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can probably be done using JQuery, but will always be jittery. I would consider a fixed DIV. Of course you could position that below the menu so it will never be higher (= closer towards the top edge) than the menu, and will maintain its position.

```
.thingy { position: fixed; right: 0px; top: 415px; width: 256px }
```

That would necessitate that there is nothing else below the menu, otherwise the bookmark icon will overlap other things.

Comment: Where did you get the top value? Is that measured from the toc bounding box? And then I have another problem: If the DIV is fixed, then the image is fixed, too. When the user drags the image somewhere and scrolls the page, the image will move. I guess I can solve this (move the image around in the DOM or use two images and toggle visibility).

Comment: @Aaron 1. yes, it's measured from your toc. 2. That would probably be fixable (no pun intended) by changing the positioning when drag&drop starts (It's called `makeAbsolute` in prototype).

Comment: I wish there was a "offset from side XXX of element ID" in CSS :-)

Comment: @Aaron true! It's technically partly possible using `position: relative` but it's not the real deal.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the image to be fixed, but still scrollable to the top of the window, then you'll need to handle the window's scroll event, and set the image's position to fixed when the image is scrolled to the top.

For an example of this, see the site navigation on [QuirksMode](http://quirksmode.org/compatibility.html).

Alternatively, you could give the entire TOC `position: fixed; right: 0;`, give the toc a width, and give the teaser a right-margin equal to the TOC's width. There would be no JavaScript requirement this way, and you'd have the entire TOC always visible.